# Any workarounds for NVIDIA driver error code 43 when passing through a GPU on VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, drivers, graphics-card, virtual-machine, gpu

I am trying to passing through an NVIDIA GPU to my guest Windows 10 on VirtualBox.

With vboxmanager modifyvm "VM Name" --pciattach command, I successfully passed the GPU to the guest OS (I was able to see the device name on the device manager after installing the NVIDIA driver).

However, when I installed the NVIDIA driver on the guest OS, the driver failed to work correctly and reported error code 43.

I did some search on this topic and found that the failure was due to the NVIDIA driver detecting that the OS as running on a virtual machine.

Is there anyone succeeded in passing through an NVIDIA GPU to a guest Windows AND make the NVIDIA driver work correctly on VirtualBox?

P.S. I know that this can be done using QEMU/KVM or some other virtual machine programs. However, I would like to know if this can also be done in VirtualBox.

Comment: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#pcipassthrough

Comment: I have already done that. What I need to solve is problem after that

Comment: do you use all requirements? linux host and a GPU without GART? read the steps again and look if you meet all requirements

Comment: Yes I am using all requirements. Otherwise I would not even be able to turn on the virtual machine at all

Comment: post more details about your hardware and software that you use on the host